# OpenCV: Colorization failure

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I am reading in an image and I would like to color in all non-zero pixels to red.  In addition, the background **only** consists of black.  The code I wrote to try and do this is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

second=cv2.imread('second.png') # read the picture

for i in range(second.shape[0]):
   for j in range(second.shape[1]):
       if second[i,j,0]!=0 and second[i,j,1]!=0 and second[i,j,2]!=0:# if it is not black pixel
           second[i,j,0]=0
           second[i,j,1]=0
           second[i,j,2]=255 # color it in red
cv2.imwrite('result.png',second) # save the colored picture
```

Here is the image **second.png**:

[image]

Here is the colored image **result.png**:

[image]

How come some of the pixels aren't colored in as red? Note that when I print the colour pixel values of those locations in `second.png` that were not red in `result.png`, I see that they aren't black.

Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, you want the BLACK pixels to become RED?

Comment: @Aphire no, opposite: non black pixels only to red

Comment: Okay your opening sentence "I am reading a picture to color in red all its black pixels" threw me Might wanna change that, it looks as if David has answered your question correctly though.

Comment: @Aphire I am sorry for the confusion, yes, it was my fault, i reedit my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `or` in your condition, such that all pixels that are not black are substituted:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

second=cv2.imread('second.png') # read the picture

for i in range(second.shape[0]):
   for j in range(second.shape[1]):
       if second[i,j,0]!=0 or second[i,j,1]!=0 or second[i,j,2]!=0:# if it is not black pixel
           second[i,j,0]=0
           second[i,j,1]=0
           second[i,j,2]=255 # color it in red
cv2.imwrite('result.png',second) # save the colored picture
```

Alternatively, you could write `if not(second[i,j,0]==0 and second[i,j,1]==0 and second[i,j,2]==0):` as the condition, which is equivalent.

Comment: your alternative works perfectly fine (with `not` and `==`) but the first solution changes the black pixels to red, but i want to keep black as black and everything else red

Comment: SORRY: your first solution works too !!!! Both of them work ! thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv::split` and `cv::merge` if you wont to leave only read channel. 
Here is C++ example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("second.png");
    cv::Mat b_g_r[3];
    cv::split(src, b_g_r);
    b_g_r[0] = cv::Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1); //blue to zeros
    b_g_r[1] = cv::Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1); //green to zeros
    cv::merge(b_g_r, 3, src);
    cv::imshow("Red", src);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

And result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by David Zwicker is certainly the way to go.  However, I would like to suggest something, and  **not** use `for` loops with `numpy` arrays.  I would suggest using a vectorized solution instead as you will most definitely get a boost in performance.  To me, this is the way `numpy` was meant to be used.

What I would do is split up the image into separate channels with [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), then check each channel independently.  We allocate a mask of the same size as one of the channels, and for each location in the image, if **any** of the channels is non-zero, we would mark this location to be `True`.  The result of this operation would be a mask where `True` denotes a non-zero pixel, and `False` otherwise.   You can use [`numpy.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html), but the standard syntax only accepts two inputs.  If you want to use this over **multiple** inputs (i.e. greater than 2), you need to use the [`reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) idiom.

Once you're done finding this mask, use [`numpy.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to determine the locations in the mask that are non-zero or `True`, and create an output image which is initially all zeroes, then you set the red channel to 255 corresponding to these non-zero locations.

Or in other words:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('second.png') # read in image

# Look at each channel independently and see if there are any non-zero pixels
# and merge them together to create a mask
mask = np.logical_or.reduce(np.split(img, 3, axis=2))

# Find those locations in the mask that are non-zero
(rows, cols, _) = np.nonzero(mask)

# Create a blank image, then set the red channel to 255 for those non-zero locations
out = np.zeros(img.shape).astype('uint8')
out[rows,cols,2] = 255

# Show image, wait for key, then close window after
cv2.imshow('Red', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

We get this:

[image]

It's totally up to you on what you want to do, but the above (to me) is more Pythonic.  Use whatever you're most comfortable with!

Comment: This is rather the precise expected behavior I want. Very complete and precise answer. Thank you very much